# Rails question: What's the optimal way to create user customisable UI texts

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a regular rails app with index, show pages, and forms.

I'd like to allow the administrators of the site to customise the default texts across the site without code changes.

For example, the admins should be able to change a page's H1 tag from "User Index" to "Customer Index", or change a form label from "User Name" to "Customer Name".

I was thinking to create a model called **ui_texts** that has two fields:

- machine_name: string
- value: string

Then, I would replace the current hard coded texts with a query like:
`Ui_text.where(machine_name:"user_name").value`

The admins would have a simple CRUD to edit the ui_texts from the admin interface.

The problem with this approach is that a complex form will generate dozens or even hundreds of database queries to populate all the UI texts.

Even if I index by **machine_name**, the extra queries will add considerable time to the page load.

I wonder what is the optimal way to achieve such functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use i18n to localize your application and set it up to use a database backend. Expect this to take a few hours of your time, it's rather cumbersome.

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html

https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#using-different-backends

After you set this up it will be trivial to create a CRUD section in your application where users can edit whatever messages they like.

Comment: Thank you! That's a clean way of doing it.